# Dotnet Core - The JSON value could not be converted to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

A have a Blazor wasm application with the following model defined as such:

```
{
    public int StaticTableId { get; set; }
    public JArray StaticData { get; set; }

    public static void RunFluent(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        EntityTypeBuilder<StaticTable> entity = modelBuilder.Entity<StaticTable>();
        entity.HasKey(p => p.StaticTableId);
        entity.Property(e => e.StaticData).HasConversion(
            v => v.ToString(),
            v => JArray.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(v) ? "[]" : v)
        );
    }
}
```

Note that `RunFluent` is executed in `DbContext.OnModelCreating`

Calling the API directly using the below function in the controller produces the correct result; a list of JSON objects.

```
// GET: api/StaticTable/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<StaticTable>> StaticTable(int id)
{
    var staticTable = await _context.StaticTables.FindAsync(id);

    if (staticTable == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return staticTable;
}
```

However, attempting to pull this data to the front-end produces the following error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: The JSON value could not be converted to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken. Path: $.projectAnalyses[0].jobInstances[4].resultsData.staticTable.staticData[0] | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 3263.`

Similar questions on SO suggest updating `ConfigureServices()` with a call to `AddNewtonsoftJson()`, however this is already in place.

Updating `StaticTable.StaticData` to be of type `JToken` also gives me an error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100] Unhandled exception rendering component: The collection type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' is abstract, an interface, or is read only, and could not be instantiated and populated.